# log4j disable rolling create files based on size

Tags: log4j

I trying to find a ready made jar/class that gives me the option to 
enable log4j write to files endlessly based on file size , what i mean is this: 
configure log4j to :
1. write to log file until file size is 10 mega 
2. when file reach to 10 mega it will be renamed to "file_"+current date suffix and thats it .
3. start new logfile go to 1

each time the file reach to 10240KB it rename the file engine.log  to engine_1.log
and then when the main engine.log reach again to 10240KB
it rename the engine_1.log  to engine_2.log
and engine.log  to engine_1.log  and so on ..
this is the action i like to AVOID !
the problem it cause for example :
so if i look at content in engine_1.log and after 10 min's the content in the same file will be changed

i just want simple writing to logs without renaming the files each time.
i hope i made my self clear .

Comment: You could just edit the log4j apender in the config file, but you need to do this programatically? Just trying to understand your requirements.

Comment: not programatically , i what that log4j just write files/logs based on size limit . so if i define each log when it equel to 10 mega new log file will be started

Answer (score 3):

Achieving this is not possible with the standard Log4j library, but it is implemented in the [Log4j Extras Companion](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/companions/extras/) library, which is a separate JAR file and can be downloaded [from here](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/companions/extras/download.html).

Standard `RollingFileAppender` performs log rotation (or rolling) based on the log file size. If the log file reached the specified size limit, a new log file is started and the old log file will be renamed to have a `_1` suffix. Existing archive logs will also be rotated with `_2`, `_3`, etc. suffixes.

What you need is to override this default log file naming policy to use current date in archive log file names instead of a counter. This can be configured with the `TimeBasedRollingPolicy` filter ([here is the documentation](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/companions/extras/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/rolling/TimeBasedRollingPolicy.html)).

Modify your Log4J configuration file (*log4j.xml*):

```
<appender name="FILE" class="org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender"> 
    <param name="Threshold" value="DEBUG"/>   
    <param name="File" value="engine.log"/>
    <param name="Append" value="true"/>
    <rollingPolicy class="org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <param name="FileNamePattern" value="engine_%d.log" />
    </rollingPolicy>
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ISO8601} %t %-5p [%c{1}] %m%n "/>
    </layout>
</appender>
```

I've taken this example configuration from the [official Log4J wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/logging-log4j/Log4jXmlFormat) (see *Filter configuration* and *More examples* sections at the bottom of the page).

**Update:**

The `RollingFileAppender` class from the extras library does not have the appropriate attribute for setting the maximum log file size as the old `RollingFileAppender` had. This property can be specified using a *triggering policy*, in this case the `SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy` should be used (documentation [is here](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/companions/extras/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/rolling/SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy.html)). The configuration of the triggering policy is the same as for the rolling policy (I show only the relevant part):

```
<appender ...>
    ...
    <triggeringPolicy class="org.apache.log4j.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
        <param name="MaxFileSize" value="10000000" />
    </triggeringPolicy>
    ...
</appender>
```

Comment: Thanks but where i define the file size ? and how the file naming should be ?

Comment: I though you wanted to DISABLE rolling (that's the title of your question). Please make it clear: you want to enable rolling based on file size, based on file date or disable rolling completely? All is possible just tell what you exactly want.

Comment: @user63898: It's more clear now, I modified my answer, hope it helps.

Comment: Im getting using log4j-1.2.13.jar and apache-log4j-extras-1.1.jar: 
log4j:WARN No such property [maxFileSize] in org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender.
log4j:WARN No such property [maxBackupIndex] in org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender.

Comment: I made a mistake, you should use `org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender` instead of `org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender`, but this class doesn't have the `maxFileSize` and `maxbackupIndex` properties. Remove thos from the configuration files.

Comment: so i have problem here ... i still need to define maxFilesSize 
to each file. how can i control the size of each log file ?

Comment: @user63898 You could have figured it by yourself by now, but see the update.